# Tactics for Solving Z3 Quantification

Tags: z3

I need to solve the following quantified formula, and I have tried some combination of tactics, but Z3 always returns `unknown`. I obtained the formula from symbolic state subsumption check that we newly implemented on [KLEE](https://github.com/klee/klee), which essentially is establishing the validity of entailment of two quantified bitvector formulas representing strongest postconditions. The following formula is the simplified form of the unsatisfiability test to establish an entailment validity. Does anyone know of the right combination of tactics to solve it or is there any reformulation that I could do to help Z3?

```
(set-logic ABV)
(declare-fun y () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8)))
(assert (bvsle (concat (select y #x00000003)
               (concat (select y #x00000002)
                       (concat (select y #x00000001)
                                (select y #x00000000))))
               #x00000000))
(assert (forall ((x (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8))))
         (let ((a!1 (concat (select x #x00000003)
                            (concat (select x #x00000002)
                                    (concat (select x #x00000001)
                                            (select x #x00000000)))))
               (a!2 (concat (select y #x00000003)
                            (concat (select y #x00000002)
                                    (concat (select y #x00000001)
                                            (select y #x00000000))))))
           (not (and (bvsle a!1 #x00000000)
                (= ((_ extract 31 0) (bvadd #x00000004 a!1))
                   ((_ extract 31 0) (bvadd #x00000003 a!2))))))))
(check-sat-using (then qe simplify solve-eqs bit-blast sat))
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Our problem can be reformulated so that the constraint can be solved by Z3. The select indices are all constants, so in this case we could simply replace x and y with normal constants instead of arrays. In that case, Z3 would show that the constraint is satisfiable. Thanks to Nikolaj Bjorner for this solution.